# TravisCI. Unable to locate gstreamer packages

Tags: debian, gstreamer, travis-ci

Suddenly, my CI script became broken. My [commit changes](https://github.com/khataev/qna/compare/4d65f2b6e696...ebb8e8fb149a) are not related with Travis server settings, while issue is missing packages, which prevent server from being [started](https://travis-ci.org/khataev/qna/builds/131479968):

```
2.44s$ sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install libqtwebkit-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base'
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-tools
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-tools'
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-x
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-x'
```

These packages successfully installed yet another [commit](https://travis-ci.org/khataev/qna/builds/129614854) back

My .travis.yml:

```
language: ruby
services:
  - postgresql
  - rack
script: xvfb-run bundle exec rspec
#env: QMAKE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-sdk-team
    packages:
      - libqtwebkit-dev
      - gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
      - gstreamer1.0-tools
      - gstreamer1.0-x
#      - libqt5webkit5-dev
#      - qtdeclarative5-dev
before_script:
  - bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production &
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - cp config/private_pub.yml.sample config/private_pub.yml
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
```

How could I substitute them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something has changed upstream. If we look at the [succeeding build](https://travis-ci.org/khataev/qna/builds/129614854#L155), and it becomes clear that the `gstreamer*` packages are installed from `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`. Apparently, these packages cannot be found there anymore.

Also, from the looks of it, it seems that `gstreamer1*` has been kind of a hack on Precise. You would be better off on a Trusty image, where they are available by default. At the moment, there is no Trusty available on the container infrastructure, but that will change. See this doc on the [different available virtualization](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments) environments.

If a full, sudo-enabled VM would fit your purpose, you can change your configuration to include:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
before-install:
  - sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

(Note: Dropped the `libqtwebkit-dev` package from this list. You'll need to check yourself how that can be added.)

Comment: Thanks, migrating to trusty solves my problem with gstreamer. But another challenge comes out. I have problems with thinking sphinx tests pass. And I don't completely understand if it is pre installed in trusty or not. In last successful build log I can see 


Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6

but in Trusty I couldn't...

Answer (score 0):

This could be a temporary failure if travis was unable to reach the ubuntu gce mirror it normally uses. Have you tried restarting via the travis page?

Comment: This problem lasts for three weeks at least. Just tried to re-run build - same effect. How could I contact with travis support about this? https://travis-ci.org/khataev/qna/builds/132604847

Comment: Still no changes to situation